# Where is the "Model" in MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mvvm

In Android, the "Model-View-ViewModel"(MVVM) pattern is sometimes used. However, despite the pattern name, most Android projects I have seen only include the "View" and "ViewModel" part, without the "Model". The android documentation also do not seem to mention about the "Model" (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#separation-of-concerns).

How is the "Model" implemented in Android MVVM pattern?

I am referring to MVVM implemented in Android(Java/Kotlin) projects, not that of C#/Xamarin.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the model in MVVM for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236691/what-is-the-model-in-mvvm-for)

Comment: No. That is an MVVM implementation in C#. I am referring to the Android-specific implementation of MVVM

Answer (score 0):

In that same link that you have sent, there is information:

"Models are components that are responsible for handling the data for an app. They're independent from the View objects and app components in your app, so they're unaffected by the app's lifecycle and the associated concerns."

The link that @a_local_nobody gave you with the C# implementation is quite correct.

Comment: I saw that information, but how is it implemented in code? There is only the Repository, ViewModel, and Fragment/Activity classes. Thanks.

Comment: @LCZ From my experience, it really comes down to the way that you structure your project in terms of folders and what goes where (apart from base architecture pattern), but you can try looking here https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1 - or take a look at my own project where I use MVVM - https://github.com/vitaliy-t/MovieExpert/tree/master/app/src/main/java/my/test/movieexpert/profilescreen I am by no means an expert in this matter, but that's how I personally approached MVVM

Comment: Ok, so there is no class named `Model`?

Comment: @LCZ in my personal experience and from what I could understand based on documentation of `Guide to app architecture` - No.

Comment: Thank you very much. I previously thought that the Model in MVVM had class name of `Model`, hence was unable to find it.